# read binary file while file only supports open = w+

Tags: r

I'm writing a package to read certain binary files. I added an example for one of the test files.
Now, `R CMD check` as well as `devtools::check()` yield the following error when checking examples:

```r
f <- system.file("tests/raa01-sf_10000-1910141950-dwd---bin", package="dwdradar")
out <- readRadarFile(binfile=f) 
   Warning in file(binfile, "rb") : file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
   Error in readBin(confile, what = raw(), n = n, endian = "little") :  can only read from a binary connection
```

`devtools::run_examples()` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From writing f to a textfile, I see it is an empty charstring "".
Copying the file to inst/extdata and referencing that solves the problem.
Apparently, `base::system.file` doesn't find files in `C:/R/library/pack/tests/` even though they're installed on my machine.
`devtools::run_examples()` calls `pkgload::system.file` and hence returns the local path in the package source folder